# Why for the first second i see this numer: -1.7976931348623157E+308?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this timer tick event:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox3.Text == "")
            {
                timer.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("אנא הכנס נתונים בתיבות הטקסט מצד שמאל כדי להמשיך");
            }
            else
            {
                timer.Start();
                Computer computer = new Computer();
                computer.Open();
                computer.GPUEnabled = true;

                foreach (var hardwareItem in computer.Hardware)
                {

                    if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
                    {
                        foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                        {
                            if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                            {
                                sensor.Hardware.Update();
                                //textBox1.Text = String.Format("The current temperature is {0}", sensor.Value);
                                double value = Convert.ToDouble(sensor.Value);
                                if (value < minTemp) minTemp = value;
                                else if (value > maxTemp) maxTemp = value;

                                label8.Text = maxTemp.ToString() + "c";
                                label8.Visible = true;
                                label9.Text = minTemp.ToString() + "c";
                                label9.Visible = true;
                                //lblMax.Text = maxTemp.ToString() + "c";
                                temperature_label.Text = sensor.Value.ToString() + "c";
                                int t = temperature_label.Text.Length;
                                if (t > 3)
                                {
                                    temperature_label.Location = new Point(238, 200);
                                }
                                timer.Interval = 1000;
                                if (sensor.Value > float.Parse(textbox3_value))
                                {
                                    Logger.Write("The current temperature is ===> " + sensor.Value);
                                    button1.Enabled = true;
                                    //  temperature_label.ForeColor = Color. // to check wich colors to use blue and red regular state and in emergency when its over 90c ?! what colors for each label ?
                                }
                                this.Select();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

At this line:

```
label8.Text = maxTemp.ToString() + "c";
```

I display the last maximum value.
For some reason on the first second I see on this line and label the number: -1.7976931348623157E+308

And after a second it's showing the correct value.
After this line I'm using label9 and display the last minimum value and in this line and label9 I don't see this number on the first second/time.

I declare the variables on the top of the form:

```
double minTemp = Double.MaxValue, maxTemp = Double.MinValue;
```

Why on the Max label8 do I see this number ?

Comment: Because for a double that IS the min value. It is the smallest value that can be stored in a double variable

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in and made sure it's not just initializing to a null / read-in value?  You can set it up on the form to be 0 at the beginning, I guess.

Comment: You are using a timer, it takes a bit of time before it ticks.  You can simply call Timer_Tick(this, EventArgs.Empty) in your constructor to hurry it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the value of `Double.MinValue`.  Note that you have the following lines which cause this:

```
if (value < minTemp) minTemp = value;
else if (value > maxTemp) maxTemp = value;
```

To resolve this, use

```
if (value < minTemp) minTemp = value;
if (value > maxTemp) maxTemp = value;
```

This way, both `minTemp` and `maxTemp` are checked every time.

Answer (score 0):

Change the lines:

```
if (value < minTemp) minTemp = value;
else if (value > maxTemp) maxTemp = value;
```

to (removing `else`):

```
if (value < minTemp) minTemp = value;
if (value > maxTemp) maxTemp = value;
```

You're not updating `maxTemp` in the first iteration because only `minTemp` is updated. This causes it to display the initial value of `Double.MinValue`.